# Executing my program from within PHP?

Tags: php, linux

This one has had me going. I have been trying to initiate a program that I wrote from within PHP (on a Raspbian system server). I have tried the usual functions for executing system commands, like system(), exec(), shell_exec(). These work for system commands such as 'date' or 'ls' without problem. 'php.ini' does not block these (obviously, since they work with some commands). No errors are kicked back (I enabled the PHP error log). The functions are called, return, and press on with no apparent execution.

For example I enter 'system("/mnt/ramdisk/program")' or 'system("./program")' or 'system("sudo /mnt/ramdisk/program")' in the PHP code. If I put a return variable in it returns as '1'. I have checked 'PS -e' to see if the program is spawned. It is not. I have disabled all std output (when I run this program manually it forks into the background--and runs for some time). I have set the permissions of the directory (and the program itself) to be executable by anyone (chmod 777). It's as if I call the bit bucket. What am I missing?

I had started with trying to run a program that was too involved. When I wrote a trivial program that only output one line and ended--it worked. So there is nothing intrinsically wrong with the system in 'blocking' my program. I just have to work out where the large program goes south (stdout, stderr redirection? What happens when the C program creates and outputs to files? If an exit(1)-type function in the C-code returns the code seen by the PHP exec()?--Etc.). There is much I don't understand about the nuances of the different calls (system(), exec(), etc.) And how file I/O in the C program might be affected by the call from within PHP.

By the way, I don't really need to return to the PHP once the C program has been started. What I am really trying to do is create GUI-fed configuration files on the browser that then are used by the C program (without having to activate an SSH terminal to start it).

Comment: Crazy idea (worked with something similar before): `exec()` a bash script that executes your program. Quick and dirty, I know, but it's worked for me when in a bind.

Comment: I tried this, but it had no effect:  $txt = "./readmate.sh";
 echo "</br>" . $txt . "</br>";
 $return = exec($txt); // Execute system command to start program.
 echo "</br> exec .sh command returned: " . $return;
The .sh is a script that contained the './program' line I have been trying before.

Answer (score 0):

Check disable functions by following command 
`echo ini_get("disable_functions");`

But if you are using **shared hosting** , `system(); exec(); shell_exec();` are blocked .

Comment: I tried this, but it had no effect: $txt = "./readmate.sh";
 echo "</br>" . $txt . "</br>";
 $return = exec($txt); // Execute system command to start program.
 echo "</br> exec .sh command returned: " . $return;

Comment: Think my comment got posted wrong.  Try this: Arshid-thanks.  Useful function.  The results match what I see in the disable_functions section of php.ini.  None of them match the system calls I have been trying.  It does tell me that no other functions are being disabled.  I did try changing the php.ini command to 'enable_functions'--no change.  The 'host' is just my Raspberry Pi.  Don't know if I have 'shared hosting' or not.

Comment: Raspberry pi is not a shared hosting :)